# Inserting a line break from a variable objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

I am pulling data into my iphone application using xml. The xml value is then placed in a variable.

example variable:

```
123 London road \n London \n England
```

The variable is then set as a label.

I want the line breaks to appear in the label, instead it is printing \n.

If i manually set the label value

```
locationLabel.text = @"123 London road \n London \n England"
```

It works as i want it to.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 7):

You have to replace the substrings `\n` (consisting of the characters `\` and `n`) with the actual linebreak character (in C-sources expressed by `\n`), e.g. by using `NSString`s [replace methods](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_117):

```
NSString *res = [myStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: +1 Ha ha, thanks for that.  I have exactly the same issue of replacing escape sequences in a completely different context and I was pondering how I was going to do that.  That's a nice clean solution

Comment: Alas, it doesn't work.  Consider the string "\\n". In that situation, it is the second backslash that should be escaped, not the n.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, the above works fine for this situation - e.g. for `myStr = @"a \\n b";`. @jer

Comment: Because you don't want to end up with a new line in the sequence \\n, you want to end up with a backslash followed by n.

Comment: It's slightly confusing because the compiler converts `@"\\n"` to the two literal characters \ and n.  However, I was talking about the sequence of three literal characters (after the compiler has done its stuff) \ \ and n. `Try [@"\\\\n" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];`

Comment: If this is how your context looks, then the above is not the solution for you. From the OP i just know there is an escape code for line-breaks, there is no mention of any other. @jer