# How to do a line break for a UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uitextfield, line-breaks

I am storing text in an SQLite database and one field looks something like this:

```
"blah blah \n\n blah blah"
```

However, when I display the text using a UITextField, my app actually displays the "\n" and doesn't break the line.  Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting a line break from a variable objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868618/inserting-a-line-break-from-a-variable-objective-c)

Comment: you are right.  thanks.  hitting close...